# Android Camera API (Java) spams empty images into Root Directory when saving Picture?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to make my own camera app (so without using intent). Most of the time it's saving the images properly into my Pictures directory, but it always spams empty images into my phone's root Directory. All of the files in my Root Directory have a 2.96 mb file size but cannot be opened. They have different filenames, an example would be "1446563497184.jpg". The images saved in my Pictures directory and have the correct file names.

I am trying to save the pictures captured with my camera just -once- into my Pictures directory, and not have any random images in my Root directory. Would anyone know how to get to this? Here is my code:

CameraDemo.java

```
package nl.arjenvangaal.takepicturev2;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback;
import android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class CameraDemo extends Activity {
    Preview preview;
    Button saveButton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); //load layout file

        preview = new Preview(this); //create new camera preview
        ((FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.preview)).addView(preview); //display new preview

        //button listener
        saveButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.saveButton);
        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                preview.camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
            }
        });

    }

    ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {

        }
    };

    /** Handles data for raw picture */
    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

        }
    };


    /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyymmddhhmmss", Locale.US);
            String date = dateFormat.format(new Date());
            String photoFile = "Foto_"+ date + ".jpg";
            File sdDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES); //mapje

            String filename =sdDir + File.separator + photoFile; //mapje + / + filenaam
            File pictureFile = new File(filename);  //uiteindelijke bestandslocatie

            FileOutputStream outStream; //me create new output

            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto opgeslagen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Foto kon niet worden opgeslagen.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Preview.java

```
package nl.arjenvangaal.takepicturev2;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.hardware.Camera.PreviewCallback;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


class Preview extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private static final String TAG = "Preview";

    SurfaceHolder mHolder;
    public Camera camera;

    Preview(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
        // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
        mHolder = getHolder();
        mHolder.addCallback(this);
        mHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where
        // to draw.
        camera = Camera.open();
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90); //Roteer het beeld 90 graden zodat het goed wordt weergegeven


            camera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {

                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera arg1) {
                    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                    try {
                        outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                        outStream.write(data);
                        outStream.close();
                        Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                    }
                    Preview.this.invalidate();
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // Surface will be destroyed when we return, so stop the preview.
        // Because the CameraDevice object is not a shared resource, it's very
        // important to release it when the activity is paused.
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera = null;
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w, int h) {
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> previewSizes = parameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes();

        // You need to choose the most appropriate previewSize for your app
        Camera.Size previewSize = previewSizes.get(0); // .... select one of previewSizes here
        parameters.setPreviewSize(previewSize.width, previewSize.height);

        camera.setParameters(parameters);
        camera.startPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.draw(canvas);
        Paint p= new Paint(Color.RED);
        Log.d(TAG, "draw");
        canvas.drawText("PREVIEW", canvas.getWidth() / 2, canvas.getHeight() / 2, p);
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/layout">

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/preview"
                android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            </FrameLayout>

            <Button
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Save" android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/saveButton"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your PreviewCallback you are storing the byte array on your root folder in the onPreviewFrame method.

```
FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d(TAG, "onPreviewFrame - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
```

Remove that code if it is not what you want to do.